# How to create a JSON in SWFT using users input data?

Tags: swift

I need to create a JSON like this:

```
{
    "var1": "1",
    "var2": "2",
    "newArray": [{
        "Deleted": false
    }]
}
```

My `Codable` looks like this:

```
struct RequestModel: Codable {
    var var1: String?
    var var1: String?
    var Treatments: [Treat]
    
}


struct Treat: Codable {
    var adminBy: String?
}
```

So, now I need to create the above JSON... I tried the following:

```
let adminBy = adminByTextField.text ?? ""
let VAR1 = var1TextField.text ?? ""
let VAR2 = var2TextField.text ?? ""

let dict  = ["adminBy":adminBy] as! NSDictionary


///And I TRY to create my JSON here


private func createRequestObject() -> RequestModel {

    let request = RequestModel(var1: VAR1,
                               var2: VAR2,
                               Treatments: dict)

    return request
}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

I don't understand why this error occurs or how to fix it.

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need an `NSDictionary`. You should be creating an array of `Treat` and passing it to your `RequestModel`.  `let treats = [Treat(adminBy: adminby)]` and pass treats to your `RequestModel(var1: VAR1, var2: VAR2, Treatments: treats)`. Though the json example you have provided doesn't match the structs that you have created.

Comment: @Andrew, that did the trick. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using an `NSDictionary` here. You `RequestModel` object requires an array of `Treat`.

You could create the array in the following way and pass it to your `RequestModel` :

```
let adminBy = adminByTextField.text ?? ""
let VAR1 = var1TextField.text ?? ""
let VAR2 = var2TextField.text ?? ""

let treats = [Treat(adminBy: adminBy)]
let request = RequestModel(var1: VAR1, var2: VAR2, Treatments: treats)
```